Displaying values instead of variable names on a adaptive card posted in teams
We are using Github Actions to post our test results after a run in our Teams channel. We are using normal connectors as of now but that won't be possible anymore in the future. That is why I am trying to understand how to work with Teams Workflows and these adaptive card.
I can trigger the workflow via Postman and via GHA but the card always shows the variables instead of the values I am sending. Can someone of you see what I am doing wrong? The adaptive card designer is working, and I even used a template from their side.
What I am sending:
{
    "title": "Please confirm your order:",
    "customer": [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
        }
    ]
}

What I am getting
is a card that displays the variable names:

${title}
Name   ${customer[0].firstName} ${customer[0].lastName}
Phone number   ${customer[0].phone}
1x  Steak
2x   Side Rice
1x  Soft Drink

What I expected is a card which uses the values I sent.

Please confirm your order:
Name   John Smith
Phone number  (555) 555-5555
1x  Steak
2x   Side Rice
1x  Soft Drink


I tried all versions from 1.2 to 1.4 but the values are never displayed in Teams
When I am using version 1.5 or 1.6 the information on the card can't be displayed at all and I am getting a card which says:
We're sorry, this card couldn't be displayed

Setup Workflow looks like this:
  and this is the template I have configured:
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "${title}",
            "wrap": true,
            "style": "heading"
        },
        {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "title": "Name",
                    "value": "${customer[0].firstName} ${customer[0].lastName}"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Phone number",
                    "value": "${customer[0].phone}"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "FactSet",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "title": "1x",
                            "value": "Steak"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "2x",
                            "value": "Side Rice"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "1x",
                            "value": "Soft Drink"
                        }
                    ],
                    "spacing": "Small"
                }
            ],
            "spacing": "Small"
        }
    ]
}


Can you try changing "${title}" -> title or `${title}`

Thank you for replying =) When I am trying      title        the card cannot be posted and I am getting following error
"code": "InvalidJsonInBotAdaptiveCard",
"message": "Microsoft.Azure.ProcessSimple.Data.Entities.Exceptions.ProcessSimpleDataException: The specified Teams flowbot adaptive card request is missing or invalid. The tracking Id is '{0}'.
There is no change in the behaviour if I am using '  instead of "  . the variable name will be displayed as before

Okay sorry I couldn't help. I tried your template and the data in the designer url and it actually works as expected and values are showing up: https://adaptivecards.io/designer/

I still appreciate your efforts. It is working in the designer for me too. Just in Teams not.

We got access to ChatGPT 4.o within our company and it helped me to find the solution. I have tested it and changed the template to a more complex one and it is still working. So the answer is not generated fully by ai. There is still some trial and error from my side involved
Template
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.3",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/title']}",
        "wrap": true
    },
    {
        "type": "FactSet",
        "facts": [
            {
                "title": "Passed",
                "value": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/results'][0]['passed_tests']}"
            },
            {
                "title": "Failed",
                "value": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/results'][0]['failed_tests']}"
            },
            {
                "title": "Total",
                "value": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/results'][0]['executed_tests']}"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "title": "View GHA Run",
        "url": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/run_url']}"
        }
    ]
}

Example Request
{
"title": "Test run results",
"results": [
    {
        "passed_tests": "100",
        "failed_tests": "11",
        "executed_tests": "111"
    }
],
"run_url": "https://www.google.com"
}

The result
Test run results
Passed  100
Failed   11
Total   111
Sabine used a Workflow template to send this card. Get template
View GHA Run

